# How do I access a Spinner's selected item when I've dynamically added the Spinner to a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-spinner

I am trying to create a simple settings page for an app.

I want to create a list of objects, whose layout I define in an XML file.

Within the layout of these objects is a title TextView, a help TextView, and a Spinner.

As I'm adding these objects dynamically in code, how do I then reference these individual Spinner views so that I can get the selected value?

I currently have a Setting object (what the list will be populated with):

```
public class Setting {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] values;

    public Setting(String name, String description, String[] values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

A custom ArrayAdapter to translate Setting objects to Views:

(R.layout.spinner_row_text_layout.xml is just a text view to define the layout of the spinner's items)

```
public class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Setting> {

    public SettingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Setting> settings) {
        super(context, 0, settings);
    }

    @Override
    // Takes the position in the array, the view to convert, and the parent of the view as parameters
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the item in this position
        Setting setting = getItem(position);

        // Check if a view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view (look at view recycling in lists)
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.settings_row_view, parent, false);
        }

        // findViewById in the given view to convert
        TextView title   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        TextView help    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.helpText);
        Spinner  spinner = (Spinner)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_row_text_layout, setting.getValues());
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        title.setText(setting.getName());
        help.setText(setting.getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And the following layout files...

Settings page layout:

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.cgillions.counter.SettingsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/settingsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for each ListView item:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helpText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/animation_settings_hint"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I start the Activity that corresponds to the Settings page layout, I get the following error:

at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:211)

at com.example.cgillions.counter.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:46)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)

This is my onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    setTitle("Settings");

    // Create a new Setting object in order to populate list
    animSetting = new Setting("Animation", getResources().getString(R.string.animation_settings_hint), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.anim_values));

    settings = new ArrayList<>();
    settings.add(animSetting);

    ListView settingsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
    assertNotNull(settingsList);
    settingsList.setAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(this, settings));

    animSpinner = (Spinner) settingsList.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    assertNotNull(animSpinner);
}
```

The error occurs on the last line - e.g. the View with ID 'spinner' cannot be found (and therefore is null). I'm accessing the Spinner incorrectly - can someone advise as to how I should do this?

I want to get the Spinner object in order to get the selected item.

Comment: the R.id.spinner is not a layout inside the listview but is a layout of the inner Views, and every row has a new instance of the Spinner, why do you need the spinner in the Activity? (and which one? the one in the first row? the second row? and so on)

Comment: What do you mean by 'is a layout of the inner Views'? I know what you're saying about each row having a new instance - how would I access each individual list item? In this case, I want the first item's spinner (as I only have one Setting in the list...)

Comment: I wanted the spinner in the activity so that I could pull the selected item and change a behaviour on a different activity.

Comment: In your code, you trying to get the each spinner's selected item in the Activity's onCreate method. Is that where you want to read the selected items? If not, you could pass a callback object to your `SettingsAdapter` and use this object in the spinner's `setOnItemSelectedListener`. This will allow you to do whatever action you wish when each spinner is changed.

Comment: @Matthew So in my Settings adapter I have created an OnClickListener, and each time I create an item I set it's listener to this variable. Within this variable I switch the clicked views' TitleText (the title of the Setting) in order to work out which item it is. This (almost) works (I think there must be a bug elsewhere as the settings aren't always changing correctly). Is this 'the best' way to do get what I want to do done? It seems pretty long, and tending towards spaghetti code - lots of bits of the functionality are all over the place.

Comment: @Charlie I agree with the messy feeling, but that is the only way I know of. Unless you have another event where you wish to "change a behavior on a different activity". Such as, if you made a single button, separate from the listview, that read the selected items of all the spinners in the listview items and made all the activity changes at once. In summary, either event based (my first suggestion) or batch based (create a button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you might try. Add an Spinner instance to your Setting class:

```
public class Setting {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] values;
    private Spinner spinner;

    public Setting(String name, String description, String[] values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setSpinner(Spinner s) {
        spinner = s;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinner() {
        return spinner;
    }
}
```

Then, in your getView() method, provide the Spinner to your setting instance:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_row_text_layout, setting.getValues());
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
if (setting.getSpinner() == null) {
    setting.setSpinner(spinner);
}
```

Then, assuming you can access your list of Settings, you can access the spinner associated with each one. If you find a Setting with a null spinner, then it never came into view in the Activity, and that would mean the user never changed it. But I don't know if that's really what you want.

This will allow you to access the spinner for each Setting, but you have no logic for storing the user's selection, or for setting the selected item in the spinner. I.e., if the spinner has options A, B and C, and the user has selected B, you can now read the B but you don't have a place to store it. The Setting class should have a field for holding the chosen value. And your getView() method should call `spinner.setSelection()` to tell it to show B as the current value. Otherwise, it will always show A regardless of what the user has previously chosen.

Comment: I like this solution. It makes sense for each Setting to have a Spinner. However when I try to read the values of each Spinner, they all have the same value (the value of the *last* Setting's Spinner added to the list).

Comment: I have 2 Settings at the moment, Animation and Background.

The following lines:

System.out.println(settings.get(0).getName());
            System.out.println(settings.get(0).getSpinner().getSelectedItem().toString());
            
            System.out.println(settings.get(1).getName());
            System.out.println(settings.get(1).getSpinner().getSelectedItem().toString());


Print Animation \n White \n Background \n White

Comment: Have you solved this yet? If not, the next thing I would try, is to setup a test of `onItemClick()` on the ListView. The third argument is `int pos` which gives you the row in the ListView which was clicked (starting at 0). See if you get an `settingsList.onItemClick()` event thrown when you select an item in your spinner. If you do, save the value selected in the spinner, in the Settings instance associated with the `settingsList.onItemClick()` event.